# I am trying to implement quicksort in Python but the output list is either skipping elements or repeating them

Tags: python, quicksort

I am very new to programming and wanted to implement `quicksort` after going through diagrams given in my book. However, I am not getting the desired sorted list as some elements are either not added or are repeated. I suspect that the problem is with how I am using recursion to sort the list.

```
array = [52, 5, 45, 2, 78, 1, 9, 57, 3]
global less_pivot_list
global greater_pivot_list

def quicksort(array):
    global less_pivot_list
    global greater_pivot_list

    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    elif len(array) == 2:
        if array[0] > array[1]:
            temp = array[0]
            array[0] = array[1]
            array[1] = temp
        return array 
    else:
        pivot_index = 0
        pivot = array[pivot_index]
        list_pivot = [pivot]
        less_pivot_list = [item for item in array if pivot > item]
        greater_pivot_list = [item for item in array if pivot < item]   
        return quicksort(less_pivot_list) + list_pivot + quicksort(greater_pivot_list)

output = quicksort(array)
print(output)
```

Here is the output: `[1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 52, 3]`

Comment: A good rule of thumb: any use of keyword `global` is fishy. There is no reason to look further until you fix this.

Comment: BTW, this `temp = array[0]`, `array[0] = array[1]` and `array[1]= temp` could be written in one line as `array[0], array[1] = array[1], array[0]` (tuple unpacking).

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you solve the issue.

Comment: @yash471994-- Rather than just being told to remove them, more fundamentally do you see why the global declarations cause the wrong result?

Comment: @DarrylG -- That's what I was thinking about. Is it because the global variables hold the list values, even after the current recursive call. In this function, `less_pivot_list` and `greater_pivot_list` simply update their list items. Is this right?

Comment: @yash471994--in `return quicksort(less_pivot_list) + list_pivot + quicksort(greater_pivot_list)`  Python evaluates from left to right, thus `quicksort(less_pivot_list)` is evaluated first.  In the recursive calls of evaluating `quicksort(less_pivot_list)`, less_pivot_list and greater_pivot_list are updated by the child calls.  So by the time you get to `quicksort(greater_pivot_list )` (i.e. 3rd term of expression), greater_pivot_list has a different (and incorrect value).  Does this make sense?

Comment: @DarryIG -- Thanks. I understood what you were saying and  to further cement my understanding , I kept a track of  the values being passed in `quicksort(less_pivot_list)` along with the updated values of less_pivot_list and greater_pivot_list by child calls and that really helped in realizing what you were saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the global declaration within the function

```
array= [52,5,45,2,78,1,9,57,3]
less_pivot_list = []
greater_pivot_list = []

def quicksort(array):

   if len(array)<2:
       return array
   elif len(array)==2:
       if array[0] > array[1]:
           temp = array[0]
           array[0] = array[1]
           array[1]= temp
       return array 
   else:
    pivot_index=0
    pivot=array[pivot_index]
    list_pivot=[pivot]
    less_pivot_list = [item for item in array if pivot > item]
    greater_pivot_list = [item for item in array if pivot < item]   
    return quicksort(less_pivot_list) +list_pivot+ quicksort(greater_pivot_list)

output=quicksort(array)
print(output)
```

this produces the output correctly sorted.

Comment: And the `global` on module level can be removed too.

Comment: As @Matthias said, "less_pivot_list = []" rather than "global less_pivot_list"